# Looking for proper GIS terminology - polygon with a cut in it

Tags: qgis, gdal, polygon, ogr

(QGIS,GDAL/OGR) I have a polygon produced by contouring that has a small short overlapping line segment. I am wondering if there is a proper GIS term for this and whether there is an automated method for its removal. I will call it a 'cut'. While a polygon with such 'cuts' are valid (non-crossing), I can't think of a reason why anyone would keep and not remove all such 'cuts' from their polygons. I have used the QGIS vertex tool to remove the vertices in question. Is there a tool in QGIS or GDAL/OGR to automatically detect and remove remove cuts such as these? I am not a GIS person. I feel that I am missing a completely obvious concept/operation.
[image: Polygon with slice]

Comment: Buffer your polygons by 0.1 m, then buffer by -0.1 m. Changes in outer borders should be minimal.

Comment: I always run a check validity on a layer for many reasons before proceeding.  I usually remove these internal vertices with a node tool selection but I suppose if I had many I would run a v.clean with a small tolerance.  Of course the best thing to do is avoid creating them using topological editing but when you get layers from others you have to do the fixing.

Comment: Thanks. I did run the GRASS v.clean but did not play with the tolerance.

Comment: This is *not* a valid polygon. The exterior ring is forbidden from being "non-simple".

Comment: Good to hear. Passes the QGIS(3.16.16)  Vector/Geometry Tool/Check Validity test. :-(